# Python function,issue with input file

Tags: python

I have function written by a colleague working in same field. So I know I should write script to execute python code,but issue of how the format of the input bbfile looks like bothers me.As I see fidlines read all the content,correct?My may concern is bbfile(tab delimited in my case),should it have three columns one for freq,other for breal and third for bimag?

```
def bbcalfunc(bbfile,nfreqlst):

    fid=file(bbfile,'r')
    fidlines=fid.readlines()
    #define the delimiter
    if bbfile.find('.txt')>=0:
        delimiter='\t'
    elif bbfile.find('.csv')>=0:
        delimiter=','

    freq=[]
    breal=[]
    bimag=[]
    for ii in range(1,len(fidlines)):
        linestr=fidlines[ii]
        linestr=linestr.rstrip()
        linelst=linestr.split(delimiter)
        if len(linelst)>2:
            freq.append(float(linelst[0]))
            breal.append(float(linelst[1]))
            bimag.append(float(linelst[2]))
        else:
            pass

    freq=np.array(freq)
    breal=np.array(breal)
    bimag=np.array(bimag)
    nfreq=np.log10(np.array(nfreqlst))

    brinterp=interpolate.splrep(freq,breal)
    brep=1E3*interpolate.splev(nfreq, brinterp)

    biinterp=interpolate.splrep(freq,bimag)
    bip=1E3*interpolate.splev(nfreq, biinterp)

    return brep,bip
```

Comment: So, are you getting an error message, or what? Also, please fix your code formatting. The `def bbcalfunc(bbfile,nfreqlst):` line isn't even in the code block.

Comment: You also forgot to close the file: `fid=file(bbfile,'r')`. **Always** open files like this: `wtih open(bbfile,'r') as fid: fidlines=fid.readlines()`.

Comment: @Igor C programmers should not edit python codes

Comment: @BhargavRao I don't think I know enough C to call myself a C programmer, but thanks for the compliment.

Comment: @Igor Buddy, Just note that indentation demarcates blocks in python, just like `{` and `}` in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the input file depends on the extension that you use, a `.txt` file will be a Tab Separated Values (tsv) file while a `.csv` file will be a Comma Separated Values (csv) file (please note that this is not a general convention, it is something that was decided by that colleague of yours that wrote the function, or maybe it's a local convention).

Each line of the file is usually composed by three {tab,comma} separated values, i.e., frequency, real part and imaginary part of a complex value.

I said *usually composed* because the code silently discards all the
lines for which the element count is less than three.

There is something here and there that can be streamlined in the code,
but it's inessential.
Rather, to answer your question re closing the file, change the first part
of the function to

```
def bbcalfunc(bbfile,nfreqlst):

    #define the delimiter
    if bbfile.find('.txt')>=0:
        delimiter='\t'
    elif bbfile.find('.csv')>=0:
        delimiter=','

    # slurp the file
    with file(bbfile,'r') as fid:
        fidlines=fid.readlines()

    ...
```